# Rails Layout: Make is so it doesn't reload the whole page everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I currently have a layout setup where it `<%yeild%>'s` the part that changes. However, I have noticed that it reload and fetches the rest of the page css, html & js that never changes while the same layout is in use.

I would like to know if there is a simple and efficient way to make it so that if the user is changing page through the tabs I have setup to navigate it only fetches the part of the page that changes. Not the navbar, the main js, etc.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Rails has a feature called Turbo Links that does this. Other than that people build single page apps with Javascript frameworks like AngularJS.

Comment: @Sunil D. From what I have read this feature is automatically enabled in rails. Is there a reason for it not working for me? I am using rails 4.1.4

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help much more. I actually disable Turbo Links b/c I am only using Rails as an API server for my single page apps (AngularJS).